# Get the total count for each type in 2 mins interval

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Get the **total count** for each **type** in **2 mins** interval.

**INPUT or Table I have:**

[image]

---

**Desired Output**

[image]

I am struggling with the Query, how can I iterate through each 2 mins.

Comment: Please edit the question and enter the Source data as text, not as image. Even better, create [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with the schema and sample data.

Comment: Do you really need the 00:02:00 - 00:03:59, Heavy, 0 row? Because conjuring data into existence tends to make things messier. Can we instead say that the absence of a particular row implies that the count for that combination is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a calendar table and then join on it to get groups:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(t TIME, tp INT, cn INT)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('00:00:01', 1, 1),
('00:00:15', 2, 1),
('00:00:16', 2, 1),
('00:00:17', 2, 1),
('00:01:59', 3, 1),
('00:01:59', 3, 1)

;WITH tally AS(SELECT TOP 720 DATEADD(mi, 2 * ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) - 2, CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME)) AS starttime,
                              DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(mi, 2 * ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) , CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME))) AS endtime
               FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1(n)
               CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t2(n)
               CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t3(n))
SELECT ta.starttime, 
       ta.endtime, 
       t.tp, 
       SUM(t.cn) AS cn 
FROM @t t
JOIN tally ta ON t.t BETWEEN ta.starttime AND ta.endtime
GROUP BY t.tp, ta.starttime, ta.endtime
```

`tally` is you calendar table. `Top 720` is just for full 24 hours.

Output:

```
starttime           endtime             tp  cn
00:00:00.0000000    00:01:59.0000000    1   1
00:00:00.0000000    00:01:59.0000000    2   3
00:00:00.0000000    00:01:59.0000000    3   2
```

If you want to include all types in each time group then you can do the following:

```
;WITH tally AS(SELECT TOP 720 DATEADD(mi, 2 * ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) - 2, CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME)) AS starttime,
                              DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(mi, 2 * ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) , CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME))) AS endtime
               FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1(n)
               CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t2(n)
               CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t3(n)),
      types AS(SELECT DISTINCT tp FROM @t)
SELECT ta.starttime, 
       ta.endtime, 
       tp.tp, 
       ISNULL(SUM(t.cn), 0) AS cn 
FROM tally ta 
CROSS JOIN types tp
LEFT JOIN @t t ON tp.tp = t.tp AND t.t BETWEEN ta.starttime AND ta.endtime
GROUP BY tp.tp, ta.starttime, ta.endtime
ORDER BY ta.starttime
```

Comment: Can you please expalin in your answer, how the `tally` is working? I am wondering and failed to understand clearly how it is working.

Comment: Can you please expalin in your answer, how the `tally` is working? I am wondering and failed to understand clearly how it is working. I mean the **1's and t1,t2,t3**.

Comment: Just do `select * from tally` right after it and see the results.

Comment: You use cross joins to get 1000 rows. Row_number() is a window function which returns you the number(1, 2, 3 ,,, 1000). And you use these numbers to get the intervals.  for 1  you get 2*1-2 = '00:00:00' as a start date and 2*1 - 1 sec = '00:01:59' as end date. For second row 2 you get: 2*2 - 2 = '00:02:00' and 2*2 - 1 sec = '00:03:59'

Comment: Instead of 1s you could use any - it doesn't matter. The main purpose here is just to produce some rows(1000 in this case because you are cross joining 3 tables with 10 rows each). t1(n) is just aliasing. You get table `t1` with column `n` and 10 rows with data{1, 1, 1, 1...1}.

Comment: Thanks boss. I now clearly understood the procedure. I am thinking of using row counts instead of using `SUM(t.cn)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   '00:00:00 - 00:01:59' AS [Time],
   [Type],
   SUM(Count) OVER(PARTITION BY [Type]) AS [Count]
FROM Your_Table
WHERE [Time] BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '00:01:59'

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
   '00:02:00 - 00:02:59' AS [Time],
   [Type],
   SUM(Count) OVER(PARTITION BY [Type]) AS [Count]
FROM Your_Table
WHERE [Time] BETWEEN '00:02:00' AND '00:02:59'

UNION ALL

...
```

Comment: The time is limitless... it can be 5 mins or even 5 days. In that case how I do it?